# Can I get the error message to be printed only once?

Tags: warning-messages, message-coding

When an error occurs, most of the messages are output once.
However, sometimes a message is output multiple times.

```
Plot3D[x + y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 1, 1}]
```

In this case, the message is output twice.
I want to print a message only once and stop execution if an error occurs. How do I write additional commands?

Comment: Is that an example? Shouldn't that be {y, -1, 1}? Also, there is a difference between warning messages and actual errors.

Comment: I set it to {y,1,1} on purpose. In this case, the message was output twice unusually. In addition, the same phenomenon occurs in commands that are output in Graphics 3D such as ContourPlot3D. I want to write the code so that the message is output only once in such a code error situation.

Comment: Normally Off is used to turn off warning messages completely, like `Off[Plot3D::plld]`

Comment: I think there is a difficulty is in determining the scope in which you want the message to appear only once.  It might be relatively simple to turn the error off after the first time it occurred in a session, but that's probably not want you want.